# Python: How to query for WHOIS information using the urlib library, no CAPTCHAS

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'd like to query for WHOIS information on specific domains through either https://lookup.icann.org/ or https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx# using the urllib library.

Due to restrictions on my device, I cannot use any other Python libraries other than those built-in, so I can't use the whois library. I can't add libraries to get around CAPTCHAS either. I can't use paid services, and I probably can't sign up for things. I cannot change these restrictions at the moment.

This is my current idea, but it doesn't appear to work with the structure of these particular sites:

```
        response = urllib.request.urlopen("url here" + domainIwantToQuery)
        html = response.read()
        html = html.decode("utf-8")
```

I want to search at least for any domain ending in ".com", ".net", all the common domain endings would be good.

Typically the domains I'm looking at have been created recently, if that information helps at all.

Could someone point me in the right direction of how to use these sites with Python using urllib, given my restrictions, and if it's even possible to do so?

Let me know if I need to add any more information or clarify something.

Comment: Many registrars obscure their registration information to the point where your requirements simply cannot be met. For example, GoDaddy increasingly anonymizes their public `whois` on port 43 in favor of a CAPTCHA-laden and generally rather useless web interface. Several TLDs, including Spain (`.es`), Pakistan (`.pk`) etc do not publish useful whois information at all any longer. Your best hope is a paid service like WhoisXMLApi, but they too suffer from similar problems (they automate port 43 scraping rather well, but don't seem to be doing much about these cases).

Comment: The idea that the response will be HTML and/or use UTF-8 encoding is problematic, too.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, I tried this code with whois.com and they just blocked me with a CAPTCHA even though I could get the HTML response back.

Comment: Maybe you could include a couple of examples of domains you want this information for? If your requirements are not "every domain everywhere" but rather a small set of `.com` domains, hopes may be slightly higher.

Comment: @tripleee I updated my response. Unfortunately I don't think I can divulge what specific domains I'm looking at, but know that they would typically end in ".com", and ".net".

Comment: The traditional commercial TLDs are available to a large number of registrars, each with its own policies and services. GoDaddy is (inexplicably) very popular, so chances are at least some of the domains you want to query will be handled by them, and so the comment above about the basically useless public `whois` of theirs is probably pertinent here.

Comment: @tripleee Tried their site manually, and they gave me a CAPTCHA. As I don't think I can get past CAPTCHAS with my current restrictions, things don't look good. :(